# Agregar cada linea de un txt a una lista de listas java

Tags: java

Necesito agregar cada linea de un txt a cada fila de un lista de listas(tendría la forma de una tabla),pero al parecer solo se guarda la última y la repite en toda la tabla.

Lo estoy intentado hacer de esta forma, pero me gustaria escuchar otras ideas gracias.

Aqui banner vendria a ser las filas y sublista las columnas

```
 public Tabla (int f, int c) 
{
    banner= new ListaAleatoria(f);

    for( int i=0;i<f;i++)
    {
        sublista = new ListaAleatoria(c);

       for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
       {



            try {
                    //Aqui agrego el metodo Linea()
                sublista.add(sublista.length(),Linea());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }


       }

       banner.add(banner.length(),sublista+"\n");
    }

}
```

Aquí retorna la linea que supuestamente quiero agregar a la lista

```
 public  String Linea() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  {
   String fichero = "C:/data/text.txt";
try {
  FileReader fr = new FileReader(fichero);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

  String linea;
  while((linea = br.readLine()) != null)
  return linea;
  fr.close();


}
catch(Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Excepcion leyendo fichero "+ fichero + ": " + e);
}
return "";
```

}

Comment: Puede subir todo el codigo,

Comment: Falta mucho código para darte una respuesta más clara, pero la función Linea no hace lo que tú quieres así como la tienes. Abre el fichero, lee la primera línea y la retorna terminando la función y por lo tanto cerrando el fichero. Eso lo hace así cada vez que la llamas. Nunca va a leer más que la primera línea. Tienes que abrir el fichero, leer línea a linea todas y luego cerrarlo. Tu diseño no tiene sentido. La función que lee las líneas es la que tiene que ir generando la lista o llamando a una función que vaya guardando las líneas en la lista y no al revés.

Answer (score 2):

un modo de leer el texto y guardarlo de forma eficiente seria usando un LinkedList o ArrayList, podrías hacerlo de esta manera o usarlo como ejemplo de como leer un .txt y guardarlo.

```
public class LeeTextos3000 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String Texterf;
        // Pongo un path de ejemplo, en el pathname debes poner el que deseas usar
        Scanner Filast = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Axpe\\Desktop\\Tal\\Text.txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s*");
        // Puedes usar LinkedList, pero de normal se usa ArrayList
        // List<String> temps = new LinkedList<String>();
        List<String> temps = new ArrayList<>();

        while (Filast.hasNext()) {
            // Va linea por linea
            Texterf = Filast.next();
            temps.add(Texterf);
        }

        Filast.close();
        String[] Textarray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);

        for (String s : Textarray) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Si quieres guardarlo en forma de tabla puedes modificar el ultimo for y poner que en cada 3 inserciones de un salto de linea, dándole forma, o si lo prefieres puedes cambiarlo a una matriz [][] tan solo sustituyéndolo por el ArrayList;